# Getting error after running 'anchor test' after creating my solana program

Tags: rust-cargo, solana, solana-cli, anchor-solana

Created a basic Solana program using 'anchor init'.

When I run 'anchor test'
I get the following errors:

[image]

Although, the file Cargo.toml exists in C:\Users\Umair\myepicproject\programs\myepicproject.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Did you able to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a problem related to using a non-Bash compatible shell with `anchor`.  Since you're on Windows, try running this through Git Bash or some other Bash-compatible shell: https://gitforwindows.org/

Comment: Actually I am running Git Bash..

Comment: So much for that... next question would be if there are any program directories in `myepicproject/programs` -- it looks like the tool is trying to build every Cargo.toml under there, ie `myepicproject/programs/program1/Cargo.toml`